# How do I use page number in php after limit was reached

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to limit the number of records per page (mysql results) using php

My current code work in terms to display the results. But all 80 results are displayed with no page numbers.

```
$stmtus = $conn->prepare("mysql query here");
$stmtus -> execute();

while ($result = $stmtus->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$client = $result['User'];
    echo $client;
    echo "<br>";

           $link = "";
           $page = $_GET['Page'];

 $limit=10  ; // May be what you are looking for
if ($pages >=1 && $page <= $pages)
{
    $counter = 1;
    $link = "";
    if ($page > ($limit/2))
       { $link .= "<a href=\"?page=1\">1 </a> ... ";}
    for ($x=$page; $x<=$pages;$x++)
    {
        if($counter < $limit)
            $link .= "<a href=\"?page=" .$x."\">".$x." </a>";
        $counter++;
    }
    if ($page < $pages - ($limit/2))
     { $link .= "... " . "<a href=\"?page=" .$pages."\">".$pages." </a>"; }
}
}  
?>
```

I am new to coding

Comment: check this link for more information : https://phppot.com/php/php-search-and-pagination-using-pdo/

Comment: That sorted my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to link posted in comments, I used the following code to solve my issue:

```
<?php
define("ROW_PER_PAGE",2);
require_once('db.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{width:615px;font-family:arial;letter-spacing:1px;line-height:20px;}
.tbl-qa{width: 100%;font-size:0.9em;background-color: #f5f5f5;}
.tbl-qa th.table-header {padding: 5px;text-align: left;padding:10px;}
.tbl-qa .table-row td {padding:10px;background-color: #FDFDFD;vertical-align:top;}
.button_link {color:#FFF;text-decoration:none; background-    color:#428a8e;padding:10px;}
#keyword{border: #CCC 1px solid; border-radius: 4px; padding:  7px;background:url("demo-search-icon.png") no-repeat center right 7px;}
.btn-page{margin-right:10px;padding:5px 10px; border: #CCC 1px solid; background:#FFF; border-radius:4px;cursor:pointer;}
.btn-page:hover{background:#F0F0F0;}
.btn-page.current{background:#F0F0F0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php   
$search_keyword = '';
if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
    $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE :keyword OR description LIKE :keyword OR post_at LIKE :keyword ORDER BY id DESC ';

/* Pagination Code starts */
$per_page_html = '';
$page = 1;
$start=0;
if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
    $page = $_POST["page"];
    $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
}
$limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
$pagination_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pagination_statement->execute();

$row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
if(!empty($row_count)){
    $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
    $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
    if($page_count>1) {
        for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
            if($i==$page){
                $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page current" />';
            } else {
                $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page" />';
            }
        }
    }
    $per_page_html .= "</div>";
}

$query = $sql.$limit;
$pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
$pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo_statement->execute();
$result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
?>
<form name='frmSearch' action='' method='post'>
<div style='text-align:right;margin:20px 0px;'><input type='text'    name='search[keyword]' value="<?php echo $search_keyword; ?>" id='keyword'   maxlength='25'></div>
 <table class='tbl-qa'>
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th class='table-header' width='20%'>Title</th>
  <th class='table-header' width='40%'>Description</th>
  <th class='table-header' width='20%'>Date</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='table-body'>
  <?php
 if(!empty($result)) { 
    foreach($result as $row) {
?>
  <tr class='table-row'>
    <td><?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['post_at']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php echo $per_page_html; ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```